# Create HexBins for shapefiles

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I usually create hexbins using the MMQGIS tools in QGIS. I would create a hex layer and intersect it with a shapefile. I've tried to create a hex shapefile and importing it into a PostGIS and tried to do an `ST_Intersects` but the result usually come up empty.

I've tried looking at other tutorials on hexbinning on PostGIS like [this](https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/25/hexbinning/) and [this](http://rexdouglass.com/spatial-hexagon-binning-in-postgis/) but they create a blanket hex bins that isn't .

Is there a way to create hex bin from PostGIS over a shapefile (truncation of hexes are ok).

Comment: If your result is empty I'm guessing you have coordinate system issues... did you ever figure this one out?